# DB2 equivalent to T-SQL's REPLICATE?

Tags: db2, functions

In T-SQL there is a method, REPLICATE(char,N), which will make a string with N values of a certain  character.  This is very helpful when querying into JDE.
Does anyone know if there is a DB2 equivalent to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [REPEAT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_bif_repeat.htm) will give you what you are looking for.

First example from the page referenced above:

```
Example 1: Repeat 'abc' two times to create 'abcabc'.

SELECT REPEAT('abc', 2)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```